# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un CSV en una lista de diccionarios?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista, diccionarios

Estoy trabajando en Python 2.7.6

Tengo un archivo csv de 20 columnas y 300 registros.

¿Cómo convierto el CSV en una lista de diccionarios?

¿Cómo hago para que el título de cada columna quede como la clave, y el registro como valor?

El csv tiene más colummnas y registros (+20/+300), pero pondré cuatro para que tengan una idea:

```
"fecha_pedido","pedido","fecha_factura_compra","factura_compra"
"13/07/2007","PED24059","13/07/2007",24052
"13/07/2007","PED24053","13/07/2007",11021
"19/10/2007","PED24060","19/10/2007",11301
"19/02/2009","PED3884","25/02/2009",17375
```

Lo que busco es que esto se convierta en una lista de diccionarios, así:

```
profit = [{'fecha_pedido': '13/07/2007',  'pedido':'PED24059',
  'fecha_factura_compra': '13/07/2007' ,'factura_compra': '24052' }, 
{'fecha_pedido': '13/07/2007',  'pedido':'PED24053',
  'fecha_factura_compra': '13/07/2007' ,'factura_compra': '11021'},
{'fecha_pedido': '13/07/2007',  'pedido':'PED24060',
  'fecha_factura_compra': '13/07/2007' ,'factura_compra': '11301'},
{'fecha_pedido': '19/02/2009',  'pedido':'PED3884',
  'fecha_factura_compra': '25/02/2009' ,'factura_compra': '17375'}]
```

De modo que pueda iterar sobre cada diccionario de cada elemento, tipo:

```
for reg in profit:
    if reg['fecha_pedido']:
        print 'hecho'
    else:
        print 'not found'
```

Comment: Mirate el módulo csv, en concreto [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) porque si quieres diccionarios en los que la clave sea el nombre de la columna es exactamente lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias! Traduciendote al neguaje newbie, entiendo que esa funcion hace lo que estoy necesitando?

Comment: En el enlace a la documentación que te muestro arriba tienes un ejemplo de uso, si quieres una lista es tan simple como en vez de  estas dos lineas `for row in reader: / print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])` hagas  simplemente `lista = [row for row in reader]`. Inténtalo, si tienes cualquier problema o duda [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/185647/edit) la pregunta y añade el código y algunas líneas del csv incluida cabecera y te ayudo, al iterar sobre la instancia de DictReader te retorna cada fila exactamente en un diccionario como el que quieres.

Comment: Gracias, lo haré e informaré a ver como salió.

Comment: y agrega el ejemplo de un csv , y te invito a publicar la respuesta sera muy util para otros

Comment: Listo, trate de hacerme los mas entendible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así funcionó:

```
with open('archivo.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)  #~ Hasta aqui crea los 
                                      #~ diccionarios
    for row in reader:
        lista.append(row)   #~ Aqui cada diccionario lo agrega a la lista
```

Saludos!

Comment: esta sección no es para agradecimientos, si tú tienes tu propia respuesta publicala y marcala como correcta, lee [answer] :)

Comment: Sorry, apenas empiezo a usar el sitio, gracias!

Comment: Si eres nuevo en el sitio te recomiendo revisar el [tour] :)

Comment: Si la lista es creada para este csv solo, puedes simplificarlo con `lista = list(reader)` en vez de `for row in reader: lista.append(row)` consigues lo mismo más eficientemente al evitar el uso de `append`.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses pandas, para leer el archivo csv y para convertirlo a lista de diccionarios con una sola linea.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('archivo')

df.to_dict('records')
```

Y ya tienes una lista de diccionarios, donde cada columna es la clave